# Should we burninate the [i] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Recently I started seeing Python questions tagged [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i) (example: [How to create a background mask from numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490534/how-to-create-a-background-mask-from-numpy-array)).

They seem to involve iteration like `for i in collection`. When I hover over this tag in a question, I see that it has "573 watchers, 2 questions". However, it doesn't have a tag wiki or any explanation of what it's supposed to mean. The tag's page is often empty because there are no questions tagged with it. Yet it still emerges sometimes.

Criteria for burnination:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
   applied? And is it unambiguous?

   I guess it describes the variable `i` used for iteration, but it seems ambiguous because it's too short and thus non-descriptive. Maybe it's about `I` the identity matrix or `i` the imaginary part of the complex number (also known as `j`).
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) are on-topic, sure, but there already is a tag for this.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   I don't think so. Okay, your iteration variable is called `i`, but the question is most likely about [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops), not the variable itself.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No: `I` the identity matrix, `i` the imaginary part of a complex number.
5. Can someone be an expert in [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i)?

   Not sure what that would even mean...

Comment: Context for CMs: the tag needs to be blacklisted, but there may also be a bug in here where the tag isn't fully removed from the system; we may be missing context here, but it seems like users without the privilege to create the tag have made it resurface several times. Examples of this also includes spam: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72352072/6296561 https://stackoverflow.com/q/72431457/6296561 https://stackoverflow.com/q/72431457/6296561

Comment: Pretty sure that this a bug, search for burninating "in" tag on MSO for more info. (Cc @zoe)

Comment: The discussion Bhargav mentioned: [Throw out the \[in\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417362/1478931)

Answer (score 18):

It's just one confused user posting one single post; just edit it out from the post and it will get cleaned up automatically. Zoe already fixed it, problem solved.

Lets talk about this bug though... 573 watchers, really?

[image]

This screenshot was taken from the (now deleted) [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i) tag list of questions.

Comment: Do we happen to have a record of previously burninating it? Can queue it up for blacklisting if we do. IIRC, watchers are preserved if the tag is destroyed and recreated

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Maybe we did, though I still don't understand what's so interesting about the tag that 573 people decided to bookmark it.

Comment: I wouldn't've written the post if it was just one single user. I saw several posts tagged with [tag:i], so I thought there was something odd going on, also considering the number of watchers. For one of these posts, I un-tagged it myself, I think (this was a couple of days ago, but I can't find that question), but now it appeared again, so it didn't get cleaned up, apparently...

Comment: "*It's just one confused user posting one single post;*" but how? The asker doesn't have enough rep to create the tag. If it didn't exist (which would happen if it wasn't tagged anywhere else), they shouldn't have been able to add it.

Comment: This is weird; I'm seeing several scattered and deleted questions with no overlap. I'm even seeing spam on a tag that theoretically shouldn't be existing. Maybe there's a bug somewhere preventing the tag from being removed?

Comment: There's "IBM i" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i, I'm guessing this is where it's coming from. We have [tag:ibm-i] which is a synonym for [tag:ibm-midrange] which is a pretty common tag.

Comment: The high watch count is easy to explain.  Not being able to find [tag:me], narcissists have to settle for watching [tag:i].

Comment: I've [status-review]ed the question to get CMs to chime in. In either case, the tag needs to die permanently.

Comment: Some history of "IBM i" here: [AS400, iSeries, and IBM-i are all the same system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372673/as400-iseries-and-ibm-i-are-all-the-same-system). Seems this was cleaned/burned etc a very long time ago, by Jeff Atwood none the less.

Comment: RE that old burnination, yes, "i" is apparently synonymous with "IBMi" or "System i" for AS/400 stuff. That could explain where a lot of old watchers came from. Would be good to look for tags like those and see if they were maybe renamed from `i` at some point.

Comment: I'm not so sure that there's a bug here. If a high rep user created the tag today and then realized that was a mistake and removed it, the tag could have been picked up by other users before it was deleted by the system. There may or may not be evidence of this happening (only easily found via SEDE later), depending on if it was removed during the grace period or not.

Comment: Only a couple of deleted posts with that tag: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1602002 there is no posthistory of the usage of the tag for current visible posts. Notice how the oldest post is from 2009.

Answer (score 10):

### Original response:

The [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i) tag is now blocked. Further investigation into the larger bug mentioned in the comments is underway.

---

### Update:

This tag (along with many other tags created on draft Articles) has now been cleaned up.

As indicated in the comments, this was one of several tags that was "stuck" due to being on a draft Article. There were a few issues involved here; originally, Article drafts allowed authors to create tags without needing the [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege or preventing blocked tags from being added; in addition, the tags would not be cleaned up by the system automatically, because they were present on Article drafts and could not be removed by anyone without editing permissions on those Articles.

The Collectives team recently went through and did a cleanup of tags created on Article drafts. I (V2Blast) worked with the mods to get lists of the affected tags, and shared them with the Collectives team for cleanup; in all, we deleted about 79 tags. The reputation requirement is also now being enforced for tag creation via Articles, as is the blocklist. The Collectives team is also working on making changes to the Article draft process to prevent this sort of problem in the future.

Thank you all for your patience!

Comment: For bookkeeping, the bug in question is primarily covered here: [Throw out the \[in\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417362/6296561)